# Android: is it possibile to alter the WebView class in order to have access to the html of the loaded page?

Tags: android, webview

I need to use a WebView to load certain webpages and dynamically change the css before showing them to the user (which means I have to delete all `<link>` tags and append the one with my css). (Why? Because I want to adapt the look of a particular site - which is not mine - for smartphones)

Now, I've seen that similar questions have been answered that the only way to modify the html before showing it to the user is by executing some javascript in the onPageFinished method; this could be a solution, but I'd like to consider other possibilities as well.

So, my questions are:

1) If I go deeper in the source of the WebView class, is it possible to find where the html is loaded from the site, so that I have direct access to the html and I can modify it as I want?

2) If yes, is WebView the class that handles the communication and retrieves the html? If else, which one is it?

3) Assuming that what I asked is possible, do you think that the application would perform better if the modification to the html where made this way instead of using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient to perform an HTTP GET and retrieve the HTML response, something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

You can now have fun with your String html and place it in the Webview

```
    WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    webview.loadData(myModifiedHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer! And well, that would be good; the only problem is that - for some reason that would take me too much to explain - I need the webview to handle every communication with that website and I'd like to only "catch" the html after it's downloaded from the website. Is this possible?

Comment: Hello Jacob. Sorry but my knowledge is too limited to help you more... But I strongly believe someone else will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by enabling JavaScript on your webview and executing

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8201246/1187469) answer for detailed procedure.