# android how to get Click String in android Webview?

Tags: android, html, string, webview

How can I get `String` from webview on its click event??

here is the image:

[image]

here i just want to fetch the blue colored strings programmatically and not the other ones.

i am using Html string Display like this in

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());   
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);                             
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", main_data ,  "text/html", "UTF-8", " ");
```

`Edit:` How i can i do this? Any one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find anything to get the text directly. A workaround could be:

When you load the webview, you parse the html. Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)

There you save all the links in a map, using the url as key and the text as value.

Then:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        String text = map.get(url);

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
      }
});
```