# Android:Getting meta name="description" in Webview

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, android-webview, meta-tags

I am making an application which uses Android WebView. This application displays page title and page description of the URL that is loaded. As a sample I am using following url

http://in.news.yahoo.com/ca-chief-slams-racist-comments-over-fawad-ahmeds-071749766.html?.tsrc=yahoo

Getting page title is easy

```
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    String title = view.getTitle();
}
```

If you do a view source of the above url in Chrome, this title is fetched from

```
<title>CA chief slams `racist` comments over Fawad Ahmed's `beer-branded kit` refusal - Yahoo! News India</title>
```

Now, I need to get meta name "description", so as to show page description, which is as given below

```
<meta name="description" lang="en-IN" content="'CA chief slams `racist` comments over Fawad Ahmed's `beer-branded kit` refusal' on Yahoo! News India. Islamabad, Sept 5 (ANI): Cricket Australia (CA) chief James Sutherland has slammed 'racist comments' aimed at Pakistan-born Australian leg-spinner Fawad Ahmed following his refusal to wear a kit displaying the logo of beer brand VB due to 'religious reasons'."/>
```

Android web view doesn't have an API to get description from meta tag "description".

How is it possible to get meta tags from document element?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by this way:

```
private class JsInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(String content) {
        //handle content
    }
}


mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "CC_FUND");

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.CC_FUND.processHTML( (function (){var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); \n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "   for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { \n" +
                    "      if (metas[i].getAttribute(\"name\") == \"description\") { \n" +
                    "         return metas[i].getAttribute(\"content\"); \n" +
                    "      } \n" +
                    "   } \n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "    return \"\";})() );");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `String.contains("meta name=\"description\"")`.

That would be the easiest method anyway. You could probably piece together a result from the code in [how to get html content from a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)

Another way would be to use the `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()` to insert the code from murala's answer, but I'm not sure how you would retrieve the result. Use my first idea.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code:
if you use `evaluateJavascript` then not need to define javascriptInterface.

call `evaluateJavascript` then use `ValueCallback<String> resultCallback` callback value.

```
                webview.evaluateJavascript(
                        """
                            function getOGPImageUrl(){
                                var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
                                for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
                                    if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "og:image") {
                                        return metas[i].getAttribute("content");
                                    }
                                }
                                return "";
                            };
                            getOGPImageUrl();
                        """.trimIndent()) {
                    // this is ValueCallback block
                    Logger.d("getOGPImageUrl: $it")
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementsByName("title");` returns a set of elements not a single element so within a cycle you could use `element.tagName` to get the tag

basicly
`document.getElementsByName("title")[0]`.tagName should work

(or)
Just use something like :

```
var author = $('meta[name=author]').attr("content");
```