# Block ads from appearing in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, adblock

I am creating a webview which loads some sites. I want to block the ads in these sites from appearing in the webview. I want it for both http and https sites. Actually i am able to do it for http sites by javascript injection.But this method will not work for https. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why does your strategy for http sites not work for https pages?

Comment: https will not allow javascript injection because of its security features @ksasq

Comment: How are you doing this javascript injection?

Comment: i used the method given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview  along with the script i needed to inject @ksasq

Comment: The best answer can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547446/android-block-ads-in-webview/39152846#39152846

Answer (score 2):

Access the website(www.adwaresite.com) using some proxy server that you own. You can create one very easily in Google app engine.

Prefetch the html of www.adwaresite.com on your server and add the base tag of www.adwaresite.com at the top of the html and send it to the android webview over http

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
<img src="stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" alt="Stickman">
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
</body>
```

Note the base tag in above code. Base tag helps to add domain to the relative urls inside html. So instead of picking the domain from the address bar , it uses this base domain specified at the top

Comment: What do you mean by 'base tag' ?

Comment: @Lazy I guess we'll never know