# There is some way to block ads in a flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, webview, ads, block

I've made a an app thats stream a video by an URL,using a webview
there is anyway to block ads on webview while video is playing?

Comment: You can do it on android using adblock webview : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60620204/7795876

Comment: gives an erro: not found

Comment: Yes, you can use my [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin, which offers the content-blocking feature through the `ContentBlocker` class!. Check my other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74611660/4637638).