# How to block a webpage advertisement when it is inside android studio Webview?

Tags: javascript, java, android, css, android-studio

I want to **block ad** from a website I am loading in an **android studio** **webview**. Say I am browsing a website in google chrome the website then showing the ad containing on the website. When I am loading that website inside my webview normally the ad is shown. I want to block that ad via the modification of java code. I have tried a method of GitHub. It's not working. Can I get the easiest and well-documented solution for it?

I try

build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android:3.0'
```

XML

```
<org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.webview.AdblockWebView 
android:id="@+id/main_webview" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Java

```
WebView webView; 

 @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") 
 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

 webView = findViewById(R.id.main_webview); 
 WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); 
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 

 webView.loadUrl("url"); }
```

or I have another idea of injecting additional CSS to solve this,

**Idea 2:** 
If I can inject an addition CSS file "`style2.css`" from `assets/style2.css` of an android studio. This may work. I can find out the div class inside that the ad is shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="google-ad">
          ***Google Ad Banner***
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      ***Webpage Content Here****
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

say class "`row`" contains an ad. I will then call `.row` class and make it `*display: none*`. But how can I inject an additional CSS file to a webpage what is loaded to my webview?

Let me clear my idea2 again with another example,
Say I am browsing "[www.google.com](https://www.google.com)" website. This google webpage has a white background. But I want to make the white background to black when I will load it to my android studio webview. By calling or injecting another CSS file from **`assets/cssbg.css.`**

`cssbg.css` code will be

```
body{
background: #000000 !important;
}
```

I have already reviewed this,
[Android block ads in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547446/android-block-ads-in-webview)

but the problem is it is difficult to understand say this portion,
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

```
 @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:")
                || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

why `.mp4`?
I just want to know the whole process in a simpler way, will you please cooperate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android block ads in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547446/android-block-ads-in-webview)

Comment: where should i add the url? say www.google.com? i didnt understand. Please Finalize the Solution!