# How to retrieve webpage data (not source code) using Android?

Tags: php, android

I am trying to pass http variables to a page on my website containing some PHP code, and retrieve a response using Android.

I directed URL.openStream() to the desired website, and collected the first string using BufferedRaader, but it gave me the first line of the source code, as opposed to what a browser would see if it were navigating the page.

This question is difficult to ask because I am not familiar enough with web language to describe exactly what I want, but...

Using Android, How would I retrieve what my browser sees on a page, and not the actual source code for the page?

Comment: Use a http connection, pass in your URL and set the PHP to receive your variables? Simple eh?

Comment: you are not sure, arent you fetching webservice using Php returning or sending Json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "webview" is what you are looking for.

Useful link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I wasn't able to find a simple way to get a String from WebView that represented the displayed content, but you pointed me in the right direction; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview  thank you!