# How to get the whole content text of html page displayed in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I have found question to read content from `webview`.I have tried i can't able to fix.

I have displayed a html page in `webview`. I need the content of that html page in a `string`

**java code**

```
WebView mainContent = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         WebSettings webSettings = mainContent.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
         mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
          mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    mainContent.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
                }
            });
         mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
         mainContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+filename.get(position));
         webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(40);
```

And in MY Activity

```
public void processHTML(String html) {

                System.out.println("======++++"+Html.fromHtml(html));
            }
```

I didn't see my anything log. How can i get the content(text) of `HTML` page in a `String`. What im doing mistake? Thanks in advance

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview

Comment: From web or local file?

Comment: @NickF from web i have dispalyed the file in webview from this i need to get

Comment: do u want display html string in web view?

Comment: @Suru no i need the text from that html page which is dispalyed in webview

Comment: Try Html.fromHtml(htmlContent);

Comment: @berserk its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the content by this way

```java
mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebSettings webSettings = mainContent.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mainContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+filename.get(position));
mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mainContent.setWebViewClient(null);    
        mainContent.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<div>'+document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML+'</div>');");
```

and in my activity

```java
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(final String html) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Spanned page = Html.fromHtml(html);
                System.out.println("content"+page);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to launch a GET petition to that page?

`responseString` is the HTML page in a String. For example:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

Launch AsyncTask like:

```
try {
        String page = new RequestTask().execute("http://myurl.com").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can'tunderstand your code.. i need to get the text from that webview

Comment: Its a get petition to a URL using AsyncTask. It returns the HTML page in a string (return responseString). You could use webview url and launch this task to retrieve its content as String.

Comment: shows Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<String,String,String> to String

Comment: Its not working.. i didn't get any error also but app minimized

Comment: @MakeitSimple Nothing in LOG and app forced close ?

Comment: How you implemented this in your code ? Did you used try catch ? You must need errors in LOG if you want to resolve, without Log Errors how can we come to know where is the issue.

Comment: tried its working only website url not for assest folder path

Comment: I tried and this solution worked. But I checked that it does not get full of web page html :(. Could you check it, bro?