# Getting Craigslist img src using JSoup

Tags: android, html, http, jsoup

I am currently trying to parse a Craigslist page using JSoup for an Android application. Here is the URL to a page that I am trying to parse:

http://seattle.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=ford&sort=rel

When I inspect the elements using Chrome, I can see that the HTML structure for an ad is as follows:

```
<p class="row" data-pid="4711759405"> 
    <a href="/see/ctd/4711759405.html" class="i" data-id="0:00U0U_d4iR9oMNMBY">
        <img alt="" src="http://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_d4iR9oMNMBY_300x300.jpg">
    </a> 
    <span class="txt"> 
        <span class="star v" title="save this post in your favorites list"></span> 
        <span class="pl">
    ....
```

Using JSoup, I am able to parse everything EXCEPT for the img tag. Here is how I am making the HTTP request:

```
document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements images = document.select("img");
```

This method will only find 2 images, none of which are ad images. I also used the Chrome plugin POSTMAN in order to replicate an HTTP GET request, and I find that there are no img tags for any of the ads. Why is this happening and how can I retrieve the img tag src URL?

Note that I am able to retrieve everything else, but the img tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ad images on the URL you gave are loaded using JavaScript after the page is loaded, that's why the initial HTML source does not contain any `img` tags.

However, there is a mapping between the `data-id` property of the `a` element in the HTML structure you posted, and the `src` property of the generated `img` tag. For example, let us consider the following element:

```
<a href="/see/ctd/4711759405.html" class="i" data-id="0:00U0U_d4iR9oMNMBY">
```

Just retrieve the `data-id` property from the `a` element, remove the part before the colon, add `_300x300.jpg` at the end, and you get the name if the image file. The full URL then becomes:

```
http://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_d4iR9oMNMBY_300x300.jpg
```

So, instead of selecting `img` elements with JSoup, select `a` elements and construct the image URLS from their `data-id` attributes.

Another solution would be to load the page in a WebView so that JavaScript gets executed, but I strongly discourage this over performance concerns.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that pattern before. I did look at the data-id at one point, but I must have missed the correlation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like they might be denying the requests server-side to stop people from doing what your doing. I'm seeing in POSTMAN the same result you are.

As a work around, you could load the page in a `webview` then inject javascript to return the entire `<html>` node. Here is a link to another SO question, that also includes alternate methods: [how to get html content from a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)