# get Html source of the PAge Loaded in WebView Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, twitter, webview

I am trying to get the full Html Source of the WebPage Loaded into the WebView and my Code is Working Fine But It's giving me null for One url( //mobile.twitter.com)
While on Other pages of Twitter(like //mobile.twitter.com/account),it is working fine.
But Give me an Error for the that One URl;
My Code:

```
            twitter_WebView.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");
            twitter_WebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.documentElement.outerHTML); ");
     class LoadListener{
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String html) throws IOException
        {
            pageHTML = html; // Giving Me Null here ///
            })
  }
```

Comment: If the HTML element is missing, the return value of *document.documentElement.outerHTML* is null.

Comment: But Html Element is must for a Webpage( twitter is loaded in WebView)
Ok,If I get Null Should I Do This: twitter_WebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<body>'+document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML+'</body>'););

Comment: Html element is for HTML documents, and WebView contain HTML code/document

Comment: Do you have any Alternate to get the Code that is being shown in the WebView ?

Comment: I don't have an idea how to resolve this problem, but i just mention you that *document.documentElement.outerHTML* return Null only if the HTML element is missing.
To get the HTML from web view, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8201246/4224337 (i haven't tested it)

Comment: Thanks for that post but I have tried that one too.
Even That One Works for Every Url But this.

Comment: Well I Found the Solution.You were Correct Maybe there was no HTMl Element.So I tried searching the Body Tag and get the Code .Thanks For Your Help Here