# Android - Eclipse How to get web view text content in string

Tags: android, eclipse

i tried different codes but fail very time. i got webview containing text i would like to take all text into string.

here i can getting webview

```
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
          browser.loadUrl("domain.com/textcontacinfile.html");
```

please help me in this

thanks

Comment: If you are trying to get HTML content in the WebView, please check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8201246/2777098

Comment: not html only text content please

Answer (score 1):

To get text content from HTML, use XmlPullParser.

Here are references:

[Google developer doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

[Tutorial on XML parsing](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html)

```
private String readText(String htmlStr) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

             String toReturn = "";
             XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
             factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
             XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

             xpp.setInput(new StringReader ("htmlStr"));
             int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
             while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                  toReturn = "Text "+ xpp.getText());
              }
              eventType = xpp.next();
             }
            return toReturn;
}
```