# send text containt of the webpage instead of url in android webview app

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, share, share-intent

I have an Android WebView app and i have added share action in it, which shares URL of the current page of the webview. but i want it to send text content of the page instead of URL. please help me with share intent. following is my code for share intent.

```
case R.id.menu_item_share: {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myWebView.getUrl());
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This Website!"));
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                break; //or, return true;
```

Comment: what type of contents do you want to send from the web page?

Comment: @Arshak website contain mostly text,  i want  share action to send that text (body of the article) instead of url of the page.

Comment: Try these links for solution : [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28000925/5744335) , [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8201246/5744335) @sagar chaudhary

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579772/android-get-text-out-of-webview

Comment: @Arshak  not working.

Comment: @MujammilAhamed not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the content of the web page, please try it like this.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("text/html;\\s+charset=([^\\s]+)\\s*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(con.getContentType());

String charset = m.matches() ? m.group(1) : "ISO-8859-1";
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), charset);
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
while (true) {
   int ch = r.read();
   if (ch < 0)
   break;
  buf.append((char) ch);
}
String str = buf.toString();
```

Comment: please tell where do i exactly add this.

Comment: I think you can make function like getContent(String url)

Comment: And please call this function case R.id.menu_item_share: { //Stirng content = getContent("your url")  Intent intent = ...

Comment: private String getContent(String url) {URL url = new URL(url);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection(); ....

Comment: it force closes app after clicking on share button.