# Android : How to get HTML content in String from WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I just want to get the HTML String from my webview for that i am trying with the following code

```
webviewTxt.loadUrl("javascript:HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.documentElement.outerHTML);");
```

But i don't know how can i get this code to string. I even don't know whether this is true code to grab the HTML String or not.

In my webview i have following String

This is a *test* **Demo**

Where "test" is written in Italic and "Demo" is written in Bold So i want to get the HTML string from above code.

Above string is just an Example, The string may be anything not the same as above string each time.

If anyone is having any idea then please guide me, I already checked so many link links from SO and other google stuff but i am not able to grab the String in HTML from Webview.

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8201246/4224337 ?

Comment: @Rami, Yes i have tried with that code, but i am not able to get the HTML string from that code.

Comment: What you get on *showHTML()* call? I used this code before and it works fine for me.