# Need to add facebook App like notifications in my app

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

[Facebook notification list]I need to add Facebook app like notifications List into my app,
    My app will generate posts and those are submitted to the servers,
    any comments added onto any post will into the applications . 
    So i need to create one notification list like facebook with relative
     time elapsed , which shows list of notifications like

```
 "Ragav  commented on post no-24, 6 mins ago" .
```

Can any one help me to how could i make notification list like Facebook,     what things need to be there to create notification list ?
Thank You !
 See the image , I was asking about this .

[image]

Comment: you have to use push notification for that!!! Reference--> http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139     http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Push notifications are not required in my application. I need to show list of notifications to the user and need to maintain read and unread count of notifications .

Comment: use GCM google cloud messaging as - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: if you want to use your server for this then you have to use push notification and GCM!!

Answer (score 0):

GCM (Google cloud Messaging).you can generate push notification wherever you need.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    // int notifyID = 1;
    int smallIcon = R.drawable.toreachmelight_blue;
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            AutoReceivenotifiation.class);
    Date d = new Date();
    int uniqueID = d.getSeconds();
    notificationIntent.putExtra("shareloc_name", group_name);
    // context.startActivity(notificationIntent);
    /*
     * notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
     * Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     */
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, requestID, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(type)
            .setContentTitle("ToReachMe")
            .setContentText(Html.fromHtml("<u>" + type + "<u>"))
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
            .setDefaults(
                    Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
                            | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSound(
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.beep));
    notificationManager.notify((int) uniqueID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: check the link attached in problem .

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

use webview and in webview use SSE html5 and get the data from webview.

[HTML5 SSE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

[How to get webview content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)

Comment: check the link attached in problem .

Answer (score 0):

This is a library you can use to get relative time text, to get 6 min ago, just now etc

https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago

Comment: check the link attached in problem .