# How to handle CSS code in my Android email app?

Tags: android, css, jakarta-mail

My app uses [javamail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to get the emails and then I use this [Html android class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) to go through the message body and apply the html tags. But this class ignores CSS code, so if I look at an email which contains such code, it looks like this:

[image]

Basically 95% CSS code and 5% content at the bottom of it (not on picture). What are my options to solve this? I didn't really find anything useful so far. (I'm a beginner.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing native to Android that understands arbitrary HTML, like CSS, [is `WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). For displaying received emails, use a `WebView`.

Comment: More or less it actually worked :) Now I have a big problem with it though, for one of the app's function I need the text from the webview. Previously it was easy to get from the textview, but after I looked around I didn't really  find a good option so far for webview, if I dont load the data from an actual website.

Comment: @ZoltánUmlauf: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview) and many others appear in [a Google search for `android get html from webview site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+get+html+from+webview+site%3Astackoverflow.com).