# How to get the Dynamic page's html in Android?

Tags: android

I tried use `Volley` to get html.But if the web page is Dynamic,it did not work.I  heard `HtmlUnit` will be helpful. But I can not use `HtmlUnit` in Android. so ,how to get the Dynamic page's html in Android?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by "dynamic ".If you want the webview can execute JavaScript,just call setJavaScriptEnabled().You can even execute JavaScript by calling  loadUrl().

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [cURL for Android](https://github.com/jahrome/curl-android)