# How to get all of html's source code in webview, android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I know this way,

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:window.local_obj.showSource('<head>'+" +
                "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
```

But looks like this only give the `<head>` tag. If I want to get **ALL** the source codes, include the comments in `<!-- comments-->`, what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get html content from a webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)