# How to get the html-source of a page from an url in android?

Tags: java, android, html

I know this question has already been asked before but the solutions doesn't work or are deprecated..

So, I want get the html code of a webpage in android in java, if somebody can help me..

Comment: You can read about [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and use that instead of the deprecated `DefaultHttpClient` in the examples. The changes required are quite small. Learning to use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) for network operations is also a good idea. And [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is also an option and it also helps in parsing the HTML "DOM tree" if that's necessary.

Comment: There's the URL scheme `view-source:[insert webpage here]` that makes browsers display the HTML source of the webpage instead of rendering it. Have you tried that scheme?

Answer (score 0):

use webview to load url in your app then use the following code to get the html

```
wvbrowser.evaluateJavascript(
        "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
         new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                Log.d("HTML", html); 
                // code here
            }
    });
```

taken [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32040564/2299040)

Comment: Call this when the page is fully loaded

Comment: Already did, I'm waiting 30s before call this and I always have `HTML: null`