# Android / Java: Programmatically login into website with Android-App

Tags: java, android, authentication

does somebody know a explicit way to **programmatically login to a website**  **in an Android-App**?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an answer:

```
web.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                                             "document.getElementsByName('authid')[0].value = '" + ID + "';" +
                                             "document.getElementsByName('authpw')[0].value = '" + PASS + "';" +
                                             "var submit = document.getElementsByClassName('inputbutton');" +
                                             "submit[0].click(); };");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't cmpletely understand what you want, but if you just need to login and see the response, you could use a webview, and parse through the html like [how to get html content from a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview?answertab=votes#tab-top).