# How to get Element of WebView by class name?

Tags: android, html, webview

I am loading website for example 'http:/example.com' in WebView,
Let this page contain a element

```
<a class="x" href="/test1">Click here</a>
```

How can I get this element 'x' and its value of href from WebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something to read HTML back in your Java code, like showed in this Answer:
[how to get html content from a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview)

Then when you have your HTML content, you need a parser to extract element (and data) you need.
In past i've used JSOUP to navigate the HTML and it worked really well, you can find it here https://jsoup.org/.

You could extract the class names and href value with this: (only a concept)

```
Document yourPage = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);    
Element aElement = yourPage.select("path to a element").first();
Set<String> classNames = aElement.classNames();
String url = aElement.attr("href");
```

If you need help, you can read [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) a pretty nice intro-tutorial from JSOUP documentation