# How to wait when page is loaded and then execute Javascript code in Android WebViewClient

Tags: android, kotlin, webviewclient

I want `processHTML` to be triggered after the webpage is done loading. I think I need:

```
document.load =
```

for this. But I don't know the correct syntax for how to put it in `loadUrl`:

```
    class JavaScriptTokenSubstractInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        fun processHTML(html: String) {
            Log.d("","html shown is loading and not the result.")
        }
    }

    val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptTokenSubstractInterface(), "HTMLOUT")
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(webView, url)
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            webView?.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');")
        }
    }

    webView.loadUrl("www.someWebPageThatIsLoading.nl")
```

What happens:
1. The loading of the page is shown
2. processHTML is triggered and it shows the HTML of the loading page
3. A few seconds go by and the page is done loading

processHTML should be triggered after the loading is done.

Comment: is that code not working ?

Comment: this may more helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki the problem is the processHTML should be triggered after it's done loading.