# How i can parse webview content?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I need parse content from webview in my application, 
is it possible? Now i can get only url page.

I tried search content in LoadFinished object, but i not found

WebView Component:

```
<template>
    <Page class="webview-page">
        <ScrollView>
            <WebView height="100%" src="https://www.fl.ru/login/"
                @loadFinished="parsePage" />
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            parsePage(webargs) {
                //I need gets content here
                console.log(webargs.url);
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {};
        }
    };
</script>
```

I expect get all html content from pageview

Comment: @Manoj, i haven't webView object in my code, only loadFinished obj.. may have a way how to refer to WebView object?

Comment: If it's getting reference to `WebView` from `parsePage` method, it will be like `webargs.object`.

Comment: @Manojm, i tried it, but webargs.object.ios has been empty...

Comment: You can't trace methods in native object, it will mostly print empty object only.

Comment: @Manoj, and how i can get webview object?? now i get error:
webView.ios.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is not a function. (In 'webView.ios.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.head.innerHTML")', 'webView.ios.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString' is undefined)
cause object ios empty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <GridLayout>
            <WebView src="https://www.nativescript.org/" @loadFinished="onLoadFinished"
                :visibility="visibility"></WebView>
            <ScrollView v-if="html">
                <Label class="h3" :text="html" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </ScrollView>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    import {
        device
    } from "platform";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                html: ""
            };
        },
        computed: {
            visibility: function() {
                return this.html ? "hidden" : "visible";
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onLoadFinished: function(args) {
                const that = this,
                    webView = args.object,
                    jsStr = "document.body.innerHTML";

                if (webView.ios) {
                    webView.ios.evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler(jsStr,
                        function(
                            result,
                            error
                        ) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log("error...");
                            } else if (result) {
                                that.html = result;
                            }
                        });
                } else if (webView.android) {
                    // Works only on Android 19 and above
                    webView.android.evaluateJavascript(
                        jsStr,
                        new android.webkit.ValueCallback({
                            onReceiveValue: function(html) {
                                that.html = html;
                            }
                        })
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

If you like support for older Android versions (API level 17 & 18), the implementation gets bit difficult. You will have to implement a `@JavascriptInterface` interface which can be written only in Java. There is already an issue reported on enabling the ability to access [Java Annotation form JavaScript](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/175). You may have to write an Android library project where you implement the `@JavascriptInterface` and utilise it to track content as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview).

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=l8YQGZ&v=2)