# How to get Elements from WebView in Jetpack Compose using evaluateJavascript()

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to view a webpage in webview and then get some elements from the page with evaluateJavascript() ...........................................................

this is the code...

```
package com.close.practice.webview

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebPageScreen(urlToRender: String, someViewModel: SomeViewModel) {
Column {

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(200.dp),
        factory = { context ->
        WebView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            addJavascriptInterface(
                someViewModel.createWebAppInterface(context),
                "Android"
            )
            loadUrl(urlToRender)

        }
    }, update = {
        it.loadUrl(urlToRender)
    })
}



}

class SomeViewModel(application: Application, private val elementValue: MutableState<String>) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun getElementById(webViewObj: WebView, elementId: String) {
        webViewObj.evaluateJavascript(
            "(function() { return document.getElementById('$elementId').innerHTML; })();"
        ) { value ->
            elementValue.value = value
        }
    }

    fun createWebAppInterface(mContext: Context): WebAppInterface {
        return WebAppInterface(mContext)
    }

    inner class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun webViewCallJs(webViewObj: WebView) {
            // Call the function that gets the element by id and stores it in a variable.
            getElementById(webViewObj, "fname")
        }
    }
}
```

and this is MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PracticeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    
                    Column {
                        val elementValue = remember { mutableStateOf("MainActivity Before") }
                        
                        // To test result before the WebPageScreen is called
                        Text(text = "First Show MAIN Before: ${elementValue.value}")
                        WebPageScreen("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp", SomeViewModel(application, elementValue))
                        
                        // to test result after the WebPageScreen is called
                        Text(text = "First Show MAIN After: ${elementValue.value}")
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what i get when running the apk
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPZdl.png)

i was expecting to get the value of the element with the id (fname), but the code didn't work

Comment: Please refer this link:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200945/how-to-get-html-content-from-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see that you are calling all the functions in your view model that you expect. You can use print statements and the debugger to verify that.

Also you are creating mutable state in the UI and passing it to the veiwModel, and then presumable expecting that the UI would be updated. Java and Kotlin are pass by value though so you can’t pass variables like that.

What you can do is create a function and pass that to your veiwModel that will allow it to update the original value instead of a copied value that is actually separate. You’ll want to check out how to organize your UI with some reading on view models, but just to get started testing your code you can do something like this:

```
update = { newValue ->
     state.value = newValue
}
```

And pass that to your veiwModel to update state.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, can you update my code with what you said and post the updated code as an answer (if you can)

Comment: Also, another question: Do you know a way that I can get the html source page from webview after it get rendered to the screen and store it in a variable?